# my entire geometry changes when i use "Loopstools>curves

Tags: add-on

Enviroment:

Blender 3.01

Windows 10 home edition 64 bit

what i did:

1.opened blender.

2.created a model.

4.Right mouse button>looptools>curves

what i expected:

the edges i slected will be received a curved shape.

what actually happend:

every edge other then the one i selected had moved.

Note:

that also happend to me when in blender 3.0

and blender 2.93.

i also tried to reset factory settings and it did not worked.

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: pls provide your model so we can check it out

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with Blender so nothing to solve here. It's just your expectation how the tool is working is wrong. Here is an explanation of the tool with some graphics that might help to understand what it's doing: [Loop Tools: Curve](https://sites.google.com/site/bartiuscrouch/looptools/curve)

Comment: Well apparently you are right, i was confusing "Curve" with "Relax

Answer (score 2):

[Curve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html)

There are two valid input methods for the curve tool. The first is to ***select two or more vertices*** on the same loop. You can do this for multiple loops simultaneously to save time.

The second method is to ***select one or more entire loops***. If a full loop is selected, the curve tool won’t operate on that loop, but on all loops perpendicular to it and use the vertices on the selected loop(s) as control points.

**Before and After apply Curve**

1. When select one vertex.[image: When select one vertex]
2. When select 2 vertex.[image: When select 2 vertex]
3. When select 3 vertex.[image: When select 3 vertex]
4. When select 2 vertex on corner.[image: When select 2 vertex on corner]

Comment: this is weird, i don't remember that ever worked that way before 0.0.

any how i tried to select a bunch of vertices of the loop rather then the whole loop and its still like its effecting the loops perpendicular to it. (IE Method 2's outcome)